# Sorting a Dictionary sans.... anything

Tags: c

I'm a student of C working with Kochans programming in C.  My challenge is to create a dictionary sorting function for a previously written program.  Where I am stumped is that I have no tools to do this with, meaning...

No Pointers
No string header
Almost no commands, and none that manipulate strings (such as strcpy).

I've been trying to use a simple bubble sort (the dictionary only has ten entries...) but as the entries are organized in a structure, ive got read only locations and am not able to assign the value (or I am doing it incorrectly, which is always a possibility).  the code is below, though the issue is in the function at the top.  The error I am getting is "cannot assign value from a read only location".

How do I accomplish this task with the restrictions?

Also, I know the code for the basic bubble sort is incomplete, but the issue I am trying to resolve is exhibited at this point and I am stumped.  Any input would be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
{
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};

int dictionarySort(const struct entry dictionary[],int entries)
{
    int x, y;
    char tempWord;
    char tempDefinition[81];

    for (y = 0; y <= entries; ++y) {
        for (x = 0; x < 15; ++x) {
            if (dictionary[y].word[x] > dictionary[y + 1].word[x])
                tempWord = dictionary[y].word[x];
            dictionary[y].word[x] = dictionary[y + 1].word[x];
            dictionary[y + 1].word[x] = tempWord;
            printf("%c", tempWord);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    const struct entry dictionary [100] = {
        {"aardvark", "a burrowing african mammal"},
        {"abyss", "a bottomless pit"},
        {"acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"},
        {"addle", "to become confused"},
        {"aerie", "a high nest"},
        {"affix", "to append; attach"},
        {"agar", "a jelly made from seaweed"},
        {"ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting"},
        {"aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers"},
        {"ajar", "partially open"}
    };

    int entries = 10;
    int dictionarySort(const struct entry dictionary[], int entries);

    dictionarySort(dictionary, entries);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you double check the title of your question? I don't understand it fully

Comment: First of all, if your words are long 15, define a constant WORD_LENGTH and use it throughout your code, so that if you decide to change it you have to change it only in one place

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Are you asking how to sort? Or are you asking how to implement strcmp/strcpy?

Comment: I would encourage you to write a function named `swap_entries()`, that when given two entries, it swaps the contents of them. It will help you make the code very readable.

Comment: Build the tools you need, test them and use them! I mean, you need `strlen()`? write it, test it and go on. What about `int compare_entries(entry *entry1,entry *entry2)`? At this point building your own `sort_entries(entry_dictionary, compare_entries)` will be straightforward.

Comment: Sorry for the typo on the title, was supposed to read "....sans anything"

Comment: uh no pointers - what a deviating exercise! That means that you need to pass parameters by value - you can do it passing structures. so, for example `int compare_entries(entry entry1,entry entry2)` and `void sort_dictionary(struct entry dictionary[] unsorted_dictionary)` sorting the passed dictionary in place (no const - can you pass the array?)

Comment: 1)  Am I incorrect that a function cannot return an array without pointers?

Comment: 2)  If I am correct, how would manipulating the string in a separate function help?  it would just place the same problem somewhere else

Comment: 3)  Why the downvote?  the poster below clearly understood the question and addressed it, I had foolishly used "const" in my arguments, which was unecessary and amateurish.  I hinted as much in my asking, but was unable to figure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary entries are `const` because you told the compiler to enforce this constraint on your parameter: `const struct entry dictionary[]` and you created the array this way too: `const struct entry dictionary [100] = { ... }`

By the way, the fact you cannot use, because of the problem's statement, string functions doesn't prevent you from writing equivalent functions. It's a good exercise for learners, and surely the reason why you were given this constraint :)

Comment: What a dope!  I removed the const and am on my way (for now).  I hear you regarding building other functions.  The exercises in the book I am using (Kochan's Programming in C) are dead on for that reason.  I've got a decent stable of them from previous exercises, but my issue was that I cant return an array from a function without pointer (to my knowledge)  Please correct me if I am wrong here.